# Convert PCIDSK file with seven layers to Geotiff without loss of layers

Tags: geotiff-tiff, geomatica

does anybody know a way to save a PCI Geomatica landsat file (PCIDSK, *.pix) as a Geotiff without loss of layers??

The Transferring layer function of Orthoengine does not work.

With the export map function I can only save a three layer Geotiff. With Arcmap it is the same thing. What about R and QGis?

Answer (score 2):

You can use GDAL's [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) command-line utility to translate all raster bands to a GeoTIFF:

```
gdal_translate my_raster.pix my_raster.tif
```

Answer (score -2):

Found the answer by myself via the manual I of PCI Geomatica:

To translate a PCIDSK file as a GeoTIFF file:

1. In the Maps tree, select the RGB layer from the *.pix file.
   The file is active in the Maps tree.
2. From the File menu, click Utility and then click Translate.
   The Translate (Export) File dialog box opens...

Comment: Problem solved by myself

Comment: Your instructions say select the RGB file but your question states a landsat file. Id suggest attacking the manual before posting.